# Yii Framework - how to retrieve data from the results shown on the page with CListView

Tags: frameworks, yii

I'm using `CListView` to show the results of a search for companies in any area. To do this, I have a table that contains the business name, address and global positioning.

Everything is perfect, however now each time results are displayed or navigated through the pagination, the results are located on a map (e.g. Google maps).

How can I obtain only the data of the results shown on page through the `CListView`?
I've seen Yii has a property `afterAjaxUpdate`, but I cannot recover the data concerning the global position coordinates.

Look at the widget:

`$dataProvider` contains business information (names, address, global position coordinates, etc.).

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                     'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                     'itemView'=>'_viewResult',
                     'emptyText'=>'No results',
                     'enablePagination'=>true,
                     'summaryText'=>' Page {page} of {pages}',
                     'enableSorting' => true,
                     'sorterHeader'=>'Order by:',
                     'sortableAttributes'=>array(
                        'stringname'=>'Name',
                     ),    
                     'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(id, data) {alert('after');}'
));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking in `$dataProvider->data`? That should hold all of the records currently available to the widget.